# Unable to load "time" package in Windows XP using runhaskell command

Tags: haskell, windows-xp, haskell-platform

I just install Haskell 7.10.3 in my Windows XP computer but when I run the command like

```
runhaskell setup.hs configure
```

it shows the error

> unable to load package time-1.5.0.1

But when I issue the command `ghc-pkg list` the package is there. What should I do to fix this error?

Comment: This question lacks sufficient detail. what package are you trying to configure/install? Why not just run `cabal configure`  (which is the recommended route) instead of calling `runghc setup.hs configure`?